# Capistrano check fails on DigitalOcean VPS

Tags: node.js, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js app to a VPS running on DigitalOcean and so far I'm getting well..very far. My understanding of *nix is very limited so please bear with me :)

I can ssh as root into my VPS (Ubuntu 13.04 x32) with my SSH keys without any problems. When I run "$cap deploy:setup" on my local machine I get this result:

```
  * 2013-09-11 12:39:08 executing `deploy:setup'
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/yable /var/www/yable/releases /var/www/yable/shared /var/www/yable/shared/system /var/www/yable/shared/log /var/www/yable/shared/pids"
    servers: ["162.243.1.207"]
    [162.243.1.207] executing command
 ** [out :: 162.243.1.207] env: sh: No such file or directory
    command finished in 118ms
failed: "env PATH=/var/www/yable NODE_ENV=production sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/yable /var/www/yable/releases /var/www/yable/shared /var/www/yable/shared/system /var/www/yable/shared/log /var/www/yable/shared/pids'" on 162.243.1.207
```

When I run "$cap deploy:check" I get the following output:

```
* 2013-09-11 12:40:36 executing `deploy:check'
  * executing "test -d /var/www/yable/releases"
    servers: ["162.243.1.207"]
    [162.243.1.207] executing command
    command finished in 67ms
  * executing "test -w /var/www/yable"
    servers: ["162.243.1.207"]
    [162.243.1.207] executing command
    command finished in 76ms
  * executing "test -w /var/www/yable/releases"
    servers: ["162.243.1.207"]
    [162.243.1.207] executing command
    command finished in 69ms
  * executing "which git"
    servers: ["162.243.1.207"]
    [162.243.1.207] executing command
    command finished in 75ms
The following dependencies failed. Please check them and try again:
--> `/var/www/yable/releases' does not exist. Please run `cap deploy:setup'. (162.243.1.207)
--> You do not have permissions to write to `/var/www/yable'. (162.243.1.207)
--> You do not have permissions to write to `/var/www/yable/releases'. (162.243.1.207)
--> `git' could not be found in the path (162.243.1.207)
```

Here's my config/deploy.rb file:

```
set :application, "Yable.com"
set :scm, :git
set :repository, "git@github.com:Yable/yable-node-js.git"
set :user, "root"
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :use_sudo, false
set :branch, "master"

role :app, "162.243.1.207"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/yable"

set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "/var/www/yable",
  'NODE_ENV' => 'production'
}
```

I'm dumbfounded as the directory mentioned (/var/www/yable/releases) does exist and that git has been installed. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Francis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed ruby 2.0.0 and Bundler and it seems to have solved my deployment issues.